# How to select rows that have column A largest than column B after pivot_table

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pivot-table

I would like to select some rows that have some column a value largest than specific column after pivot table. Follow a sample of the pivot table.

```
|ListingCategory    |Auto   |Baby   |Boat   |Business
|Occupation         |       
|Accountant/CPA     |43.0   |9.0    |NaN    |225.0
|Administrative     |85.0   |13.0   |NaN    |126.0
|Analyst            |74.0   |7.0    |4.0    |193.0
|Architect          |1.0    |3.0    |NaN    |11.0
|Attorney           |7.0    |4.0    |1.0    |80.0
|Biologist          |4.0    |NaN    |NaN    |10.0
|Bus Driver         |11.0   |NaN    |NaN    |12.0
|Car Dealer         |5.0    |NaN    |NaN    |9.0
|Chemist            |7.0    |NaN    |NaN    |5.0
|Civil Service      |27.0   |2.0    |NaN    |36.0
```

I've got the answer using this code.

```
for occupation in list(t.index):
    print((t.loc[occupation] >= t.loc[occupation,'Debt Consolidation']))
```

The answer looks like:

```
...
Auto                  False
Baby&Adoption         False
Boat                  False
Business              False
Cosmetic Procedure    False
Debt Consolidation     True
Engagement Ring       False
Green Loans           False
Home Improvement      False
Household Expenses    False
...
```

Is there a best way to do it? How can I a built a table like a pivot table but with `True` and `False` values.

Result example:

```
|ListingCategory    |Auto   |Baby   |Boat   |Business
|Occupation         |       
|Accountant/CPA     |False  |False  |False  |False
|Administrative     |False  |False  |False  |False
|Analyst            |False  |False  |False  |False
|Architect          |False  |False  |False  |False
|Attorney           |False  |False  |False  |False
|Biologist          |False  |False  |False  |False
|Bus Driver         |False  |False  |False  |False
|Car Dealer         |False  |False  |False  |False
|Chemist            |False  |False  |False  |False
|Civil Service      |False  |False  |False  |False
```

Thank!

Comment: where is Debt Consolidation?

Comment: It's a column like `Auto`, `Baby`,`Boat` and `Business`. I removed the column `Debt Consolidation` to simplfy the table.

Answer (score 1):

You can just try

```
df.ge(df['Debt Consolidation'],axis=0)
```